# Are there any changes to the CodeDom API in .net 4?

Tags: .net, codedom

Are there any changes to the CodeDom API in .net 4?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx

- new features
- bug fixes
- things marked as obsolete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff652744.aspx

2 types with new members.

- System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider - contains 1 new member:

  ```
   CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider(String, IDictionary<String, String>) method
  ```
- System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo - contains 1 new member:

  ```
   CompilerInfo.CreateProvider(IDictionary<String, String>) method
  ```